# Initialize struct members with corresponding array elements, when the number of struct members equals the array length

Tags: arrays, go, struct, slice

I have such a struct and an array definition:

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
        A int,
        B int,
        C int,
        D int,
        E int,
}

arr := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Is there a way or a built-in method that I can efficiently create a new `MyStruct` object, with each member initialized with `arr` elements in order? (like, A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5)

Comment: Ideally you should use arrays with arrays. Otherwise you come up against the type system. So if you can, try and have an array in MyStruct instead of the individual properties.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. You have lo list the values in a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

```
m := MyStruct{A: arr[0], B: arr[1], C: arr[2], D: arr[3], E: arr[4]}
```

Or if you use an unkeyed literal:

```
m := MyStruct{arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]}
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WfcQjlW8C3p).

You could do it using reflection, but using it (and using unkeyed literal) is fragile. Changing the fields or their order may result in errors which may go unnoticed (without compile-time errors).

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, I should stress that the real-life, production code answer for this solution is @izca's, which I will report here before you go any further down the rabbit hole:

```golang
m := MyStruct{A: arr[0], B: arr[1], C: arr[2], D: arr[3], E: arr[4]}
```

But there must be other ways to do it. If you're a C programmer, you'll know that if you have a struct and an array which are of the same size, they can be casted, right?

---

So here it is, with C-style type casting (conversion in Go) using the `unsafe` package:

```golang
func main() {
    arr := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    q := (*MyStruct)(unsafe.Pointer(&arr))
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", q)
}

type MyStruct struct {
    A int
    B int
    C int
    D int
    E int
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7wPbAkl4iQV)

**Should you actually use this? No.** I should stress this is something to toy with and you should not really do this without a very good reason. The package `unsafe`, as can be quite clearly inferred from its name, is unsafe. It gives no guarantees and may break anything from the garbage collector, to cgo, to cross-compiling if not using appropriately. Nevertheless, taken for granted that the memory representation of structs remain consistent (which, I stress, is *not* defined by the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) and as such is implementation-dependent), this solution will keep working.

One fun thing to note here is that the `*q` and `arr` both point to the same thing in memory. Which means you can do fun things like this:

```
arr := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
q := (*MyStruct)(unsafe.Pointer(&arr))
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", q) // => &main.MyStruct{A:1, B:2, C:3, D:4, E:5}
arr[0] = 0xFFFF
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", q) // => &main.MyStruct{A:65535, B:2, C:3, D:4, E:5}
```

Of course, aside from being a fun experiment, this also means generally keeping the reference in real code is a bad idea. So if you *must* use the unsafe solution, you should copy by value so that you know that it's not going to reference the original array.

```
// with the extra asterisk, called indirect,
// q will be type MyStruct and the example above will fail
q := *(*MyStruct)(unsafe.Pointer(&arr))
```

---

Finally, a more real-life solution, but ineffective unless you have a struct with many many fields (in which case, you should probably just use code generation, and why are you using such a large struct anyway?)

```
arr := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
v := reflect.ValueOf(&MyStruct{}).Elem()
for i, val := range arr {
    v.Field(i).SetInt(int64(val))
}
fmt.Printf("%#v\n",v.Interface().(MyStruct))
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6dxCfu938G5)

**Should you actually use this? Not really** - but it is better than using unsafe, because the `reflect` library keeps the [Go 1 compatibility promise](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat). Note however that this will be the slowest of all solution, especially once you add all the checks in place that you would need to actually work on this in real life. As stated above, in general if you do have that many fields to justify using reflect to shrink your code, you should first ask yourself what good is it to have a struct that big, and if you do have a good answer to that, then the real solution is to build a code generator which does the copying of the array into the struct.

(The point of this answer is to show that yes, indeed, there are ways you can actually solve OP's problem - but there are also very valid reasons they should not be used!)